# How to get all Java file in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

Is it possible to get Java file from react-native projects .
By default there are 2 java activities (MainActivity and MainApplication Activity) that we can get from android folder. But suppose I have created 10 JS files in react native, can I get the java file for all 10 JS files?

Comment: I think it won't happen, JS files won't change to java files after build

Comment: Thanks .. So I guess there would be only 2 by default java file.

Comment: Yes, there will be only two java files

Comment: I am trying to decompile apk file lets c

Comment: If you are trying to unpack apk file then you can see all js files which you have created.